# Pandas: Multi-index second-level slicing by integer

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, multi-index

I have a multi-index dataframe that look like this:

```
In [45]: df
Out[45]: 
                    Last  Days to expiry
Date       Ticker                       
1988-06-23 COU88   15.65         48 days
           COV88   15.65         78 days
1988-06-24 COU88   15.65         47 days
           COV88   15.56         77 days
           COX88   15.75        108 days
1988-06-27 COU88   15.10         44 days
           COV88   15.30         74 days
1988-06-28 COU88   15.27         43 days
           COV88   15.27         73 days
1988-06-29 COU88   14.97         42 days
           COV88   14.92         72 days
1988-06-30 COU88   14.85         41 days
           COV88   14.80         71 days
```

With two levels for indexes (namely 'Date' and 'Ticker').
I would like to slice it by integer taking for all dates the first row, meaning the first ticker. The result should look like this:

```
                    Last  Days to expiry
Date       Ticker                       
1988-06-23 COU88   15.65         48 days
1988-06-24 COU88   15.65         47 days
1988-06-27 COU88   15.10         44 days
1988-06-28 COU88   15.27         43 days
1988-06-29 COU88   14.97         42 days
1988-06-30 COU88   14.85         41 days
```

Also, if possible I would like to filter the columns to get only the column named 'Last'. I do not manage to get the right syntax for df.iloc

Thanks a lot for your tips

Comment: IIUC then I think `df.groupby(level='Date').first()` should work

Comment: It works perfectly fine! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you think there is a way to make it work with df.iloc though? Just out of curiosity

Comment: I'm not able to find a method that is simple, you could `reindex` by constructing a new index that removes the duplicate values but this isn't as simple as the `groupby` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `groupby` on the first index level and call `first`:

```
In [173]:
df.groupby(level='Date').first()

Out[173]:
             Last Days to expiry
Date                            
1988-06-23  15.65        48 days
1988-06-24  15.65        47 days
1988-06-27  15.10        44 days
1988-06-28  15.27        43 days
1988-06-29  14.97        42 days
1988-06-30  14.85        41 days
```

Comment: Works fine, thanks again. I am looking into groupbys now